# checkbox toggles true and remains checked when first fired

Tags: javascript, react-native

When the page is visited for the first time, `pushNotificationEnabled` is `null`. When I check the check box, `notificationReminder` is true, so the checkbox remains checked. How can I uncheck the checkbox on first press?

```
const onNotificationToggle = (notificationReminder = false) => {
    onDateChange(toDate(dateToUse));
    callbackNotification(notificationReminder, reminder.reminderType);
  };

<Checkbox
  checked={reminder.pushNotificationEnabled ?? true}
  ...
  onPress={() =>
          onNotificationToggle(reminder.pushNotificationEnabled)
        }
  />
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I correctly understood the question, you want to show the checkbox as true only when `pushNotificationEnabled === null`, then on the next press you want to mark it as `false` but is showing `true`.

What you want to do is to create a state for handling the value for the checkbox. You could initialize the value the same you tried to handle the value for the checkbox.

```
const [isNotificationEnabled, setNotificationEnabled] = React.useState(reminder.pushNotificationEnabled ?? true)

const onNotificationToggle = (notificationReminder = false) => {
    setNotificationEnabled(prev => !prev)
    onDateChange(toDate(dateToUse));
    callbackNotification(notificationReminder, reminder.reminderType);
  };

...
<Checkbox
  checked={isNotificationEnabled}
  ...
  onPress={() =>
          onNotificationToggle(reminder.pushNotificationEnabled)
        }
  />
```

That would be the easiest to handle that change with a state. Other than that you would need to create some helper variables and would be not ideal. Check your `onPress` method to adjust where needed